# Read format category from PDF using itextsharp

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext, acrofields

I can read the fields from a pdf using C# and iTextSharp. Any way to identify the format of a text field as well?

[image: Field Format Category]

Comment: what you select as format category and options in acrobat is written into the pdf as JavaScript code. Thus, to identify this, you need to parse the JavaScript code in the pdf associated with the field.

Comment: thanks @mkl. How to go about that. I tried accessing their 'AA', 'F' and 'JS' (PdfName) dictionaries but not sure what to do next.